# Collapse Database tree/view in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, shortcuts, catalog-pane

I often find myself having to scroll WAY down into a database, and wish to simply collapse the database using the left arrow key (as is possible in ArcMap). The left arrow key will only collapse the database when the actual database is selected, rather than from anywhere within it (e.g. at the bottom of a long stack of Feature-Classes.

I've searched the [ArcGIS Pro Docs here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/the-project-pane.htm), but it does not seem to be mentioned.

Are there any hotkeys to collapse a database?

I have tried CTRL+Arrows, Shift+Arrows, Alt+Arrows, and the same mix with, for example, HOME, PageUp, etc. to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @Keggering](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416433/collapse-database-tree-view-in-arcgis-pro#comment677862_416433) there is an existing ArcGIS Pro Idea to have [Navigating Catalog with back arrow](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/navigating-catalog-with-back-arrow/idi-p/1115536) implemented:

> In ArcMap, you can collapse folders/gdbs/datasets by clicking the back
> arrow anywhere within the folder/gdb/dataset. For example, if a
> feature class within a dataset is highlighted, the first time clicking
> the back arrow will make the highlight jump to the feature dataset.
> The second time collapses the dataset, the third time it jumps to the
> gdb, the fourth time collapses the gdb, then it jumps to the folder.
> It always jumps to the folder/gdb/dataset above and, when the back
> arrow is pressed again, collapses it. This way, you can collapse and
> open the entire catalog with just the back and forward arrows. This
> helps navigating the catalog easily.
>
> In ArcGIS Pro, opening folders/gdbs/datasets by using the forward
> arrow works. However, collapsing a folder/gdb/dataset only works when
> the folder/gdb/dataset is already highlighted. If you have a dataset
> with a lot of feature classes and the one at the bottom is
> highlighted, you first have to navigate all the way to the top to
> reach the dataset in order to collapse it.